# Is there any way to integrate spherical harmonics over the surface of a unit sphere in python?

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to integrate this in Python

```
f1 = lambda phi, theta: ( np.conj(sph_harm(m1, l1, theta, phi)) \
                           * sph_harm(m2, l2, theta, phi)     #theta--> 0-2pi, phi-->0-pi
                  * np.sin(phi) / np.power(1+epsilon*np.cos(n*phi), l2))

coeff1 = (l1*l2*(l2+1)) /(2*l1*(l1+1))
result = coeff1 * term1
print(result)
```

where *m1*, *l1*, *m2*, *l2* have certain values. For example *m1,m2*=-2, *l1,l2*=2.
I have also used Mathematica to check the values I get from python. They don't match for different values. For example, for the above mentioned values of *m1,l1,m2,l2*, from python I obtained *0.01673* while Mathematica gives me *1.001433*. For other higher values of *l* and *m*s the difference is monumental sometimes.

Then, I have tried *Gaussian quadrature* method to numerically calculate my result. Though it matches for some values of *l* and *m* with the result from Mathematica, It does not hold for all values.

The weird thing is I found the problem occurring only when I consider `np.sin(phi) / np.power(1+epsilon*np.cos(n*phi), l2))` in the integration. If I only try to integrate the spherical harmonics, it does not show any difference. Do you have any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: **Note:** open ended and opinion based questions that boil down to subjective responses are generally not a good fit for this site, since there generally is not a single correct answer but a range of opinions based on different approaches. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post.

Comment: ...and epsilon is what?...If the denominator diverges or almost diverges, one may run into problems

Answer (score 0):

Note in many cases on potential theory, I was better of with something like

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import simps

xl = np.linspace( a, b, A ) 
yl = np.linspace( c, d, C )
xx, yy = np.meshgrid( xl, yl )
zz = xx.copy()
for i in range( len( yy ) ):
    for j in range( len( xx[0] ) ):
        x0 = xx[ i, j ]
        y0 = yy[ i, j ]
        zz[ i, j ] = f( x0, y0 )
result = simps( simps( zz, xl ), yl )
```

rather than using `dblquad`.